# How do you store and load a single element numpy array?

Tags: numpy, data-retrieval

When I store and load a numpy array I have no issues unless the array only has a single element. When this happens, I am able to store and retrieve it, but the resulting type is not an array.

I was expecting that I would be able to retrieve the single element as I do multiple element arrays

```
    import numpy as np

    # set up the lists
    listW = ["The Dog","The Cat"]
    list = ["The Pig"]

    # convert lists to arrays
    arrayW = np.array(listW)
    array = np.array(list)

    # Displaying the original array
    print('ArrayW:', arrayW)
    print('Array:', array)
    print('ArrayW[0]:', arrayW[0])
    print('Array[0]:', array[0])

    # storage files
    fileW = "C:\\Test\\testW"
    file = "C:\\Test\\test"

    # Saving the original array
    np.savetxt(fileW, arrayW,  fmt='%s', delimiter=',')
    np.savetxt(file, array,  fmt='%s', delimiter=',')

    # Loading the array from the saved files
    testW = np.loadtxt(fileW, dtype=object, delimiter=',')
    test = np.loadtxt(file, dtype=object, delimiter=',')

    # print out results
    print("testW:", testW)
    print("test:", test)
    print("testW[0]:", testW[0])
    print("test[0]:", test[0])
```

When you run this, you get the following output:

```
ArrayW: ['The Dog' 'The Cat']
Array: ['The Pig']
ArrayW[0]: The Dog
Array[0]: The Pig
testW: ['The Dog' 'The Cat']
test: The Pig
testW[0]: The Dog
```

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed
The error is due to the fact that the read in value 'test' is not an array. This works if the stored array has more than 1 value.

Comment: Specify `ndmin` when using `loadtxt`. Read the docs!

Comment: Did you ask this yesterday?

Comment: Thanks!  I did read the docs, but I missed it !  Will try better next time